# Bath each time after intercourse by having iud

Tags: salat

I find impurities after intercourse...but in morning again even taking gusul because of my iud so is it necessary to shower again an again if I see?

Comment: Plz help mee in this

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. What is iud?